# How to write this complex equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

What should I do to enter the following equation in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
AP = \frac{100}{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\delta^{13} C}{1000} +1\right)x ARC} +1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: As suggested by Steven B. Segletes, you can also try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
AP = \frac{100}{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\delta^{13} C}{1000} +1\right)\times ARC} +1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suggest `\times ARC` rather than `x ARC`

Comment: I wasn't sure if that cross-looking glyph was a normal x in that font or a `\times` operator. I'll add you suggestion for completeness.

Comment: \delta does not work in the equation, but everything else works well - thank you!

Comment: Since the `x` is not shown in *italic*, I assume it is a multiplication.  The spacing is also a clue.

Comment: It is multiplication. The \delta written as is produces '0`~0` in its place

Comment: @mef022 it's quite odd that a simple `\delta` would give problems.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes makes sense.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes agreed - it does not work though and if I change it to \Delta, then delta appears, but the weird extra zeroes and apostrophes are still present. \delta does not appear at all

Comment: @mef022 I think the problem is your TeX installation, try uninstalling everything and doing a new clean installation. Never heard of greek letters giving problems. It's probably unrelated but try using the `amssymb` package

Comment: @mef022 Consider the possibility that you have some strange non-printing characters in your source code.  Suggest removing the problematic `\delta` and some surrounding text and retype it in.